# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b004a type #0x1d

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've found Similar questions but the Answers Vary.

This is my First release And i'm not really sure how to debug this.

Ive gotten reports about the app not opening because of this But I have No Clue why

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lionmarketing.ecombeta, PID: 9327
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lionmarketing.ecombeta/crc64d5f9129d1236dab5.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b004a type #0x1d is not valid
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b004a type #0x1d is not valid
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2099)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1111)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at crc64d5f9129d1236dab5.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc64d5f9129d1236dab5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
    ... 9 more
```

How Do I Track down this Resource?

Found the Rescource its a Color still not sure how to fix this however

```
        // aapt resource value: 0x7F050035
            public const int design_default_color_primary = 2131034165;
```

Comment: Please find your `Resource.designer.cs` in application, then open it, press `Ctrl+F`, filter the `0x7f0b004a `,  found the file name, open your Resources folder. find this file, If it is existed and check the Build action is AndroidResources and the file name must not use other characters except A to Z, 0 to 9, and '_' . You can try to delete the bin and obj folder, rebuild you project.

Comment: I found it its design_default_color_primary But it says its invalid This isnt a File its a Constant how do I fix this?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Updated Question got any idea's?

Comment: `design_default_color_primary` this file related to the android native resource. Did tou close your VS, then try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folder in your project, rebuild you project. If this issue is disappear.

Comment: Try a fresh build. :D
Delete /bin and /obj folders and compile again.